# Reinitializing Simulators in XCode

Tags: xcode

My Simulators are destroyed somehow after installing different Xcode Versions on my machine, moved and renamed them etc. . Is it possible to remove all current Simulators listed inside the Devices Manager and do a clean reinstall or do i have to remove and add them manually ? I tried to reinstall Xcode with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to remove / Add all of them, or whatever type you want. Go to

```
Xcode > Window > Devices
```

From here, scroll to the bottom, where you will see header saying "Simulators". Those are all simulators that you created (or system created), you can right-click and delete them. There is also button "+" at the bottom, where you can readd them.

Here is screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

Hope it helps!

EDIT: **If you want to delete them all at once**, please use following script, as it is not possible to remove them all at once from the UI:

https://gist.github.com/cabeca/cbaacbeb6a1cc4683aa5

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the answer i was looking for. Sure, you can remove them but it is not possible to remove all at once. You have to do this for each one separately which is a bummer.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. Basically googling could have solved the problem really easy :D. Anyway, answer accepted √